# FLSUN QQ doesn't print and stops at Z=15 mm

Tags: ultimaker-cura, delta, flsun-qq

When I try to print something that is not the test model already on the SD, which means when I try to slice something in Cura 4 and than I start the print, the nozzle stops at Z=15 mm and only the extruder motor goes foward and backward. I tried to modify the G-code but I didn't solve the problem. I need help because it's my first delta 3D printer and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you add an image of your print and the stl image?

Comment: Did you use the pre-configured profile in Cura?

Comment: have you configured z-offset yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distance of 15 mm is about the height of the probe or Z-offset. That can be a clue.

Compare the G-code from the testprint with the G-code you sliced. It can give you other clues.